# How to call unique() on dask DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dask

How do I call unique on a dask DataFrame ?

I get the following error if I try to call it the same way as for a regular pandas dataframe:

```
In [27]: len(np.unique(ddf[['col1','col2']].values))

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-34c0d3097aab> in <module>()
----> 1 len(np.unique(ddf[['col1','col2']].values))

/dir/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.pyc in __getattr__(self, key)
1924             return self._constructor_sliced(merge(self.dask, dsk), name,
1925                                             meta, self.divisions)
-> 1926         raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key)
1927
1928     def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Won't `len(np.unique(ddf[['col1','col2']]))` in itself work?

Comment: Nope, it just returns 1. This is because the output of

    `np.unique(ddf[['col1','col2']])`  is 
      `array([dd.DataFrame<getitem..., npartitions=12>], dtype=object)`

Comment: what is the wanted result? removing duplicated rows by two columns subset?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For both Pandas and Dask.dataframe you should use the drop_duplicates method

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 1, 2], 'y': [10, 10, 20]})

In [3]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[3]: 
   x   y
0  1  10
2  2  20

In [4]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [5]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

In [6]: ddf.drop_duplicates().compute()
Out[6]: 
   x   y
0  1  10
2  2  20
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with dask==2022.11.1

```
ddf.symbol.unique().compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Dask, but they appear to have a subset of Pandas functionality, and that subset doesn't seem to include the DataFrame.values attribute.

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html

You could try this:

```
sum(ddf[['col1','col2']].apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=0))
```

I don't know how it fares performance-wise, but it should provide you with the value (total number of distinct values in col1 and col2 from the ddf DataFrame).

Comment: you can't use apply on axis=0 in dask (so far), so this won't work